# Polar plotting in Python (arc circle with no origin)

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot something that looks like the following image.

[image: Quarter Circular Domain]

I have successfully plotted a quarter circle that includes the origin, which looks like the following:

[image: Polar Plot with Origin].

But I wish to make it look like the first image.

Can this be done in Python?

Comment: Pretty much anything can be done in Python ;) Please post what you've done so far and where you struggle.

Comment: Just a quick solution in case you can't find anything better: You can use a `patch` from `matplotlib` to draw a white circle centered at the origin to the radius you want which will cover the part of the plot you don't want.